# Button background color/text change inside datatable in PrimeFaces

Tags: jquery, css, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a datable and inside that I have commandbuttons as column. I would like to change the color of the commandbutton on select and deselect. For example, RED when not-selected/deselect and GREEN when selected.

My Datatable looks like:

```
<p:dataTable id="interfaces"
    value="#{studentBean.studentDataModel}"
    var="studentDetails" emptyMessage="No Student found."
    selection="#{studentBean.selectedStudents}" >

    <p:column headerText="Select this Student" style="width:1%">
        <p:commandButton value="Select"
            action="#{studentBean.saveThisStudent}"
            styleClass="non-selected-button-background-color">
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

Below is what I am having inside default.css

```
.non-selected-button-background-color {
    background-color: blue
}

.selected-button-background-color {
    background-color: green
}
```

Now how can I achieve the functionality?

Updated the functionality:
1) All the commandbuttons are initially having blue color
2) Once I click a button, it's color should change to green
3) Clicking again on the same button, color should change to blue
4) Clicking on another button will work below --

- If there is any button with green, make it blue first
- Then change the clicked button's color to green.

Comment: Please define "select" and "deselect". This is ambiguous in this question as you're using `<p:dataTable selection>` without `<p:column selectionMode>` which is confusing. Are you using `<p:column selectionMode>`? Or do you mean that the button itself should act as a toggle? Please clearly elaborate the UI requirement.

Comment: @BalusC: Sorry for the problem. Now updated the requirement

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem comes from your style. You only replace the background color, but some primefaces style use image as a background in dataTable.

Replace

```
background-color: green;
```

by

```
background: green;
```

and I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Put following two lines in `<p:dataTable>` tag.

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" oncomplete="abcd()" />
<p:ajax event="rowUnselect" oncomplete="abcd()" />
```

Define the js functions such way. Here I have change css of hole row. You can change particular column of the corresponding row.

```
var abcd = function() {
var row= $('div.interfaces>table>tbody>tr');
$(row).each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("ui-state-highlight")){
        $(this).find('button.non-selected-button-background-color').css({'font-style':'italic'});
    }
    else {
    $(this).find('button.non-selected-button-background-color').css({'font-style':'normal'});
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: var row = $('div.myForm> interfaces>tbody>tr'); This is what I did, but it is not working. Any idea why?

Comment: @ Sudipta Deb : You just add attribute `styleClass="interfaces"` and `selectionMode=""` to `<p:dataTable>`. Then try this `var row = $('div.interfaces>table>tbody>tr')`. you have to catch the each row of table dynamically created. This way is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You use the default or special primafaces theme.So firstly you need to set
background-image css attribute none. Because this themes use the background image that components. Here is the simple usefull primefaces button css inherited class.

```
.styleFilterCommandButton-BackgroundColor,
.ui-widget-content .styleFilterCommandButton-BackgroundColor,
.ui-widget-header .styleFilterCommandButton-BackgroundColor*
{
    background-image:none;
    background-color: #ee4400;  
}
```